# Does elasticSearch or MongoDB suits my needs?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'll have reactjs webapp with nodejs server. Besides regular things like regular users profiles etc, i'll need to have the most effective and scalable solution for the purposes listed below. I understand that I'll need to rewrite some parts again and again over time, but DB choice is fundamental thing, so i hope i'll select the right one.

**Full-text search**. I'll have this json structure:

```
items: {
  [guid]: { // txt
    parent: [guid],
    path: '/root/dir/subdir/',
    created: timestamp,
    updated: timestamp,
    access: 'rwa', // rwa/rw-/r--/---
    owner: user_name,
    title: 'string',
    text: 'string',
    comments: {...}
  },
},
```

`Items` will potentially contain millions of records. Each record's `text` property may contain from few words till, say, 100k characters. Users will be slightly updating and growing this records all the time.
I'll need to perform search based on `title` and `text` properties. I'll have to use `path` property to search among items with specific path. For example: "find first 20 records where `title` or `text` contains `some words` and `path` begins with `/root/dir` sorted by `title/path/created/updated` property"

**Viewed-like statuses.** Next thing i need is to mark each viewed page as "viewed" for user in order to gray out a url to it. Apparently, user might go through thousands of pages each time and there might be a lot of users. I guess "bloom filters" might help me with that, but i have no idea, YET, how i'll implement that.

**News feeds.** Well, that's nothing unusual, regular news feed with subscriptions, trandings and recommendations. I like the solution described [here](http://www.quentinsuire.com/presentations/a-news-feed-with-elasticsearch/#/).

Thank you for help!

Comment: Elasticsearch is not meant to be a "database" per se.  If you treat it as one, you will run into issues on ES updates where you might need to reindex, thereby losing all of your data if you do not have it stored elsewhere.  ES is more suited for search capability when you sent data to it from your primary data source.  In other words, it might be wise to have both, but use ES strictly for full text searching.

Comment: @ryanlutgen, thank you for suggestion! May be mongodb will do the job alone? MongoDB has it's own full-text search, so if i understood you correctly, the only reason to use elasticSearch is to make full-text search more sophisticated.

Comment: @stkvtflw Yes correct, ElasticSearch is more sophisticated. For basic search you could use the mongodb text index. combined maybe with regex search. Make sure you have the correct index(es).

Comment: @ryanlutgen, ok, got it. One more clarification: if i will use mongodb only, how difficult it will be to add elasticSearch later? I mean, it's a big deal to migrate from, say, SQL database to noSQL, but elasticSearch integration shouldn't force me to rewrite most of the logic like that, correct?